# A sequence+ divisibility proof contest math

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, divisibility

Consider the following sequence where
$ x_{1}=2018$,  $x_{2}=1$ and $$x_{n+1}=2018x_n +2019x_{n-1}$$ for $n\ge 2$ 
Show that there must exist a term in the sequence divisible by $2018^ {2018}$

Comment: I would recommend using induction.

Comment: @Displayname how ?

Comment: Try to use $x_{n+1}+x_{n} = 2019(x_{n}+x_{n-1})$.

Comment: If.possible can you give the answer seewon lee ?